# How to set behaivor to bottom sheet dialog without adding to xml layout?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to show a BottomSheetDiyalogFragment dynamically with passing some parameters when a onClick event.

```
InfoBottomSheetDialogFragment dialog = InfoBottomSheetDialogFragment.newInstance("param1", "param2");
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "InfoBottomSheetDialogFragment");
```

Also, I want to set behaivor to the fragment.

```
BottomSheetBehavior infoBtSheetBehaivor = BottomSheetBehavior.from(findViewById(R.id.info_bottom_sheet));
infoBtSheetBehaivor.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
```

When I include the fragment xml layout on main layout, how to reach it for passing parameters?
Or, when I add the fragment programatically, how to set behaivor it? Interesting situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `BottomSheetDialogFragment` dynamically and set behaivor when `setupDialog` like this:

In your `InfoBottomSheetDialogFragment` class:

```
// Delete onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method for avoiding double inflating.
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@Override
public void setupDialog(@NotNull Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);

    View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.info_bottom_sheet, null);
    dialog.setContentView(contentView);

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();

    if(behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
        ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED);
    }
}
```

Add dialog dynamically where you want and set parameters:

```
InfoBottomSheetDialogFragment dialog = InfoBottomSheetDialogFragment.newInstance("param1", "param2");
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "InfoBottomSheetDialogFragment");
```